# Genre of "Do You Only Wanna Dance" (Mya)

Tags: identify-this-genre, genre-characteristics

I was watching Havana Nights where [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uX_8d-XwSyc) really captured me. I haven't heard any song with having such rhythm before. What is the genre of this kinda music ? Salsa, latino pop or what ?

Also, what is the drum-like thing that is keeping the rhythm ? Its not drums but probably something like that, with very distinct beats(?), I donno if you get which I am talking about. It was present in all the music from this movie, we don't hear this instrument in the pop songs that we hear.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to be a modern pop song built on top of a sample of a traditional Cuban salsa song.  I can't identify the exact sample, but the rhythm and horns are very reminiscent of [Salsa](https://youtu.be/BtiNsILXB4E?t=219).  You can compare Cardi B's recent hit [Like It](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTlNMmZKwpA) for a similar fusion.

The rhythm probably isn't a single instrument.  Salsa rhythm sections are typically built around a combination of [congas and bongos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-q5X4ymvXt).  There might also be a [guiro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUzSkxZYr-Y) in the mix, and maybe even a [cabesa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU3giPL-Fs4) or [other shaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7SJq1pYORY) instrument.  Bells of various types are also common, but I'm not hearing them on this recording.